# Порядок слов в предложении, или Можно ли не трогать?

Tags: стилистика, порядок-слов

О Стендале - рабочий момент:

> И вот этот нелюдим (А ПОЧЕМУ - НЕЛЮДИМ? К "НЕЛЮДИМУ" НИЧЕГО ИЗ
>   ПРЕДШЕСТВУЮЩЕГО НЕ ПОДВОДИТ), а ныне ранний классик реализма,
>   старательный аналитик, человек, который всю жизнь нёс в себе войну
>   между собственным Рассудком и собственным Чувством, увидел
>   «Сикстинскую Мадонну». Примечательно, что это полотно было создано
>   Рафаэлем около 1513 года для алтаря церкви монастыря Святого Сикста II
>   в Пьяченце по заказу папы Юлия II — в честь победы над французами,
>   вторгшимися в Италию. И вот Мари-Анри — француз и воин, **вошедший
>   сюда победителем, пусть через века** — при виде шедевра величайшего из
>   идеалистов мироздания лишается чувств.

Можно ли не трогать?

Или - как переставлять?

*И вот Мари-Анри — француз и воин, вошедший сюда победителем, при виде шедевра — пусть через века — величайшего из идеалистов мироздания лишается чувств.*

Или - чем помочь тексту?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, что **надо** трогать.

[Из написанного ранее.]

1. *Обычный вояка, кавалерист, который участвовал в итальянском походе Наполеона I и в войне 1812 года с Россией, а выйдя в отставку — как многие, вместо прочего, посвятил своё время самообразованию.*

Союз **а** — лишний.
Кто это — многие? Те, кто вышел в отставку? Или те, кто посвятил время самообразованию? Вместо чего — прочего? Мне во всяком случае непонятно.

Я бы написала чуть проще:
Обычный вояка, кавалерист, который участвовал в итальянском походе Наполеона I и в войне 1812 года с Россией, выйдя в отставку, посвятил своё время самообразованию.

2. *Ещё в юности он занимался рисованием, поэтому начал пописывать в стол дилетантские статьи-компиляции по истории искусств, потом уже и страшно наивно «О любви», чуть позже — незатейливые путевые очерки.*

Как вариант:
Ещё в юности он занимался рисованием, поэтому сначала пописывал в стол дилетантские статьи-компиляции по истории искусств, и только потом невозможно наивно**е** «О любви», а чуть позже — незатейливые путевые очерки.

3. Обратите внимание на абзацы (подряд):
   *И вот этот самый известный теперь Стендаль...

   И вот этот нелюдим...

   И вот Мари-Анри...*

Если *это задумка такая,* то мне она "не смотрится".

---

Теперь о том, что непосредственно в вопросе.

Я вижу так:
И вот этот ранний классик реализма, старательный аналитик, человек, который всю жизнь нёс в себе **сражение** между собственным Рассудком и собственным Чувством, увидел «Сикстинскую Мадонну». Примечательно, что это полотно было создано Рафаэлем около 1513 года для алтаря церкви монастыря Святого Сикста II в Пьяченце **—** по заказу папы Юлия II, в честь победы над французами, вторгшимися в Италию.

"Нелюдимские наклонности" ранее не обозначены (убрала); заменила войну на сражение (она уже была и ещё раз будет); перенесла тире (слишком длинное пояснение) — для визуального разделения Сикста II и Юлия II.

И так:
И Мари-Анри, француз и воин, вошедший сюда победителем — при виде шедевра величайшего из идеалистов мироздания,  шедевра, пережившего века и войны, — лишается чувств.

Надеюсь, что-то пригодится.

Comment: Римулик, там Инга или, скорее всего, внезапно обаянная мною менеджер сайта (грамотная!) поправила "путеЩественницу"... Инга говорит, что завтра купит (задорого) ***про-аккаунт***, тогда читающий сможет общаться с нею в чате (она ссылку выдаст). Вопросы с ответами я ей переправляю, но вносить правку она сможет (под моим бдительным надзором) в етом *про*. Про "нас" я спросила: у модераторов, здесь не помещается, следом дам ещё коммент-ссылку. Спасибо!

Comment: https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/385/%D0%93%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2

Answer (score 1):

*И вот Мари-Анри —  **француз и воин, вошедший сюда победителем, пусть даже через века,** — при виде шедевра величайшего из идеалистов мироздания лишается чувств.*

Я бы оставила авторский вариант без правки, запятую только надо бы добавить (она относится к вставке).

Вроде бы всё понятно. Картина посвящена победе итальянцев над французами в 1513 году, а через века сюда  приходит  победителем  французский воин, который участвовал в итальянском походе Наполеона I.

**Добавлю еще.**

Мне авторский вариант этого предложения нравится, **никакие правки ему не нужны.** Нравится в том плане, как я понимаю тему.

Стендаль — человек с особой организацией психики, тонко чувствующий искусство. Что именно повлияло на него, когда он лишился чувств, не стоит определять: возможно, это очень сложные переживания, чтобы давать им оценку, перечислять что-то, фантазировать на эту тему. Мне это представляется некорректным вторжением в сферу чувств.

В авторском варианте, как мне кажется, другой подход. **Он рисует необычность ситуации, перекличку веков и событий.** Остальное читатель должен почувствовать сам.

Comment: Шаронушко, Стендаль не мог войти через века, он до шестидесяти не дожил, это шедевру были века. В твоём варианте три "и", а мне бы расправиться с третьим тире, когда четвёртое напрашивается. Предложи ещё что-нито. И автор приглашает глянуть на электронную версию (где Римуля сразу углядела на обложке прозёванное: путеЩественница). См. *бесплатный фрагмент*: https://ridero.ru/books/obryvki_iz_realnostei_potegurim/